# Why game latency fluctuates aggressively during day?

Tags: networking, ping, tcp, gaming, latency

I play World of Warcraft (uses TCP) from India, on a server located in France. I get 180-200ms in-game past midnight which is quite comfortable for me, and unfortunately the best I can get due to the distance.
During daytime however, latency is anywhere between 400-2k ms even though a ping via cmdprompt still shows ~200ms at the same time. Traceroute :

```
    C:\Users\Ace>tracert 37.187.172.200

Tracing route to ns372348.ip-37-187-172.eu [37.187.172.200]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  [snip]
  3     *       16 ms     *     1.1.1.1
  4    30 ms    25 ms    29 ms  4.231.88.202.asianet.co.in [202.88.231.4]
  5    73 ms    73 ms    73 ms  125.19.22.85
  6   176 ms   178 ms   181 ms  182.79.222.169
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8   208 ms   194 ms   186 ms  be11-1188.rbx-g2-a9.fr.eu [91.121.128.88]
  9   194 ms   219 ms   217 ms  be100-1120.fra-5-a9.de.eu [37.187.232.96]
 10   229 ms   203 ms   204 ms  be1-1171.sbg-g2-a9.fr.eu [37.187.232.94]
 11   205 ms   214 ms   210 ms  vl20.sbg-g2-a75.fr.eu [178.33.103.203]
 12   190 ms   215 ms   223 ms  be50-7.sbg-4b-a9.fr.eu [188.165.9.76]
 13   205 ms   206 ms   203 ms  ns372348.ip-37-187-172.eu [37.187.172.200]

Trace complete.
```

Pathping :

```
C:\Users\Ace>pathping 37.187.172.200

Tracing route to ns372348.ip-37-187-172.eu [37.187.172.200]
over a maximum of 30 hops:
  [snip]
  3     *     1.1.1.1
  4  4.231.88.202.asianet.co.in [202.88.231.4]
  5  125.19.22.85
  6     *        *        *
Computing statistics for 125 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address
  [snip]
  3   13ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  1.1.1.1
                                2/ 100 =  2%   |
  4   13ms     2/ 100 =  2%     0/ 100 =  0%  4.231.88.202.asianet.co.in [202.88.231.4]
                                1/ 100 =  1%   |
  5   75ms     3/ 100 =  3%     0/ 100 =  0%  125.19.22.85

Trace complete.
```

The issues I see here are the packet losses, and the long-winded route my connection goes through. Also perhaps the difference in TCP vs ICMP latencies? Please advice if these are what causes the huge lag I face in-game, and if so, what I (or my ISP) can do about it. I'm still very new to all this, so kindly explain in detail. Thank you!

PS: I've read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/814760/game-latency-increases-during-day-not-shown-in-ping-command) prior to writing mine and while it was informative, I was unable to find an actual solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be network congestion. India is 3.5 hours ahead of France. Midnight in India would be about 9 PM in France, which is when people are already starting to go to bed. 2 PM in India is about 11 AM in France, which is when people are at work and using their computers.

Comment: Yes, it could be network congestion. And traffic always has an effect on latency. But then why does it only affect in-game latency and not the ping via cmdprompt ?

Comment: Because the ping is a single, tiny packet. The game requires many, large packets.

Comment: I tried continous TCP pings (of 1500 MTU) which yielded same normal latency as ICMP pings. Since TCP is the protocol used by WoW, TCP pings should be very similar in size and number to that used by game. Or am I not following you correctly? Please elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

Like Moshe mentioned, you're connecting during a peak bandwidth time for your ISP.

It looks like ACT broadband is a fast and affordable ISP in India.

http://www.techverse.net/top-5-ultra-fast-download-speed-and-affordable-internet-service-providers-in-india/

For a much faster connection up to 1GB/s, check out Startup Village: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-fastest-Internet-speed-in-India

If you're using Wifi, either move the router/PC closer to each other, or try a hard-wire ethernet connection.

For info about your connection to your ISP, do an ookla internet speed test