# Windows 7 how to do simple traceroute with ping?

Tags: windows-7, networking, cygwin, traceroute

On mac, I can do this:

```
> ping -DRo computerhope.com
```

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125068/is-there-an-equivalent-utility-to-linuxs-tracepath-for-os-x

And it will basically do a simple tracepath. Can I do the same thing on Windows 7? How about with cygwin?

Comment: I think I found an answer: https://superuser.com/questions/915657/how-to-simulate-traceroute-using-ping

Comment: tracert/ ?     in a windows command prompt

Comment: You need not only show the command but also the output and what info is relevant for you. Are you expecting a Window user is aware of OS-X utility output ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I do the same thing on Windows 7?

You can use [pathping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PathPing):

> Pathping is a TCP/IP based utility (command-line tool) that provides
>   useful information about network Latency and Packet Loss at
>   intermediate hops between a source address and a destination address.
>
> It does this by sending "echo request" packets via ICMP and analyzing
>   the results.

And

> Trace route and provide network latency and packet loss for each router and link in the path. Combines the functionality of PING and TRACERT.

Source [PathPing - IP trace - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/pathping.html)

Example output:

```
Tracing route to eu.newerth.com [87.117.228.107]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

[snip]

  3  hlo-lc0001-cr102-ae10-218.core.as9143.net [213.51.166.82]
  4  asd-tr0610-cr101-ae6-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.158.82]
  5  ae5-125.ams29.ip4.gtt.net [77.67.64.65]
  6  xe-7-2-1.lon25.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.107.38]
  7  iomart-gw.ip4.gtt.net [46.33.94.2]
  8  610.net2.north.dc5.as20860.net [62.233.127.182]
  9  87.117.212.42
 10  eu.newerth.com [87.117.228.107]

Computing statistics for 250 seconds...
            Source to Here   This Node/Link
Hop  RTT    Lost/Sent = Pct  Lost/Sent = Pct  Address

[snip]

                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  3   46ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  hlo-lc0001-cr102-ae10-218.core.as9143.net [213.51.166.82]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  4   53ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  asd-tr0610-cr101-ae6-0.core.as9143.net [213.51.158.82]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  5   39ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  ae5-125.ams29.ip4.gtt.net [77.67.64.65]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  6   60ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  xe-7-2-1.lon25.ip4.gtt.net [141.136.107.38]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  7   73ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  iomart-gw.ip4.gtt.net [46.33.94.2]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  8   56ms     1/ 100 =  1%     1/ 100 =  1%  610.net2.north.dc5.as20860.net [62.233.127.182]
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
  9   56ms     1/ 100 =  1%     1/ 100 =  1%  87.117.212.42
                                0/ 100 =  0%   |
 10   50ms     0/ 100 =  0%     0/ 100 =  0%  eu.newerth.com [87.117.228.107]

Trace complete.
```

For more information see my answer https://superuser.com/a/814919/337631.